# SQL SERVER: Select column not returning a value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, select

```
SELECT * from dbo.TableName WHERE [Customer_ID] = "90210"
```

`Customer_ID` is a `varchar(64)`

I keep getting an error message saying

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name '90210'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use single quotes in your `WHERE`

```
 SELECT * from dbo.TableName WHERE [Customer_ID] = '90210'
```

Comment: Just to add a bit: Double quotes are sometimes used for specifying odd column names.

Answer (score 1):

Your query will run fine if you use `SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF`